# How can I use ngModel inside custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wrote a custom directive that also contains a text input.
I want to be able to link that text input to an ng-model - optionally.
That is to say, if the user passes in ng-model, have it propagate to the text input inside it.

Directive markup:

```
<div my-directive ng-model="query"/>
```

Template for directive something like:

```
<div class="...">
  <div class="...">
    <input type="text"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use the isolated scope two-way-data-binding sign `"="`

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vnxtKgiAQhbR1AWDqgp8?p=preview):

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      model: "=ngModel"
    },
    templateUrl: "myDirective.html"
  }
})
```

This is the template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myDirective.html">
  <div class="...">
    <div class="...">
      <input type="text" ng-model="model"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: That simple, huh? I was thinking I would have to use `^ngModel` and I'm not yet quite sure how. :) Thank you.